# cant get a variable equal in a loop

Tags: python, loops, random, input, var

So I'm just trying to learn programming/coding. and I'm trying to make a loop where the computer guesses at random a number that I put in (the variable), I mostly the loop with the "while" and "if/else" loops down but like...idk how to put the variable in. I'm sure there are other things wrong with the code. Its just a simple one since I actually just started 2 days ago. here is the code

```
input = var
x = 0
counter = 0

while x == 0:
    from random import *
    print randint(1, 3)

    if randint == var:
        x = 1
        count = counter + 1
        print (counter)
        print "Good Bye!"
    else:
        x == 0
        counter = counter + 1
        print (counter)
```

Comment: `randint == var` cannot be true, you're comparing the _function_ with an integer.

Comment: `input` is a built-in function. Don't assign `var` to it.

Comment: Yes, there are some key problems with your code. I suggest stepping away from your code for a bit and taking the time to learn the fundamentals of Python. A good place to start would be [_The Python Tutorial_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/#the-python-tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

```
if randint == var:
```

is always `False`. `randint` is the random *function*, `var` is an integer (well, it *should* be).

You mean:

```
r = randint(1,3)
if r == var:
   ...
```

(store the result of the random function to be able to display it *and* test it, calling it again yields another value, obviously)

and yes, the first line should be `var = int(input())` to be able to input an integer value.

Answer (score -1):

Updated according to the comments:

I just made a working version of your program, your input would be 1, and computer would randomly guess from 1,2,3 until it gives the correct answer.

```
#input = var this line is wrong as pointed out by others
input =  1 # this is your input number
x = 0
counter = 0
import random

while x == 0:
    #from random import * this will import too much in the while loop according to comments

    #randint(1, 3) this line is wrong
    randint = random.randint(1, 3) # computer guess from 1-3, then you should assign random generated number to randint
    print(randint)

    # if randint == var:  this line is wrong, you can't compare randint to var.
    if randint == input: #
        x = 1
        count = counter + 1 
        print(counter)
        print("Good Bye!")
    else:
        x = 0
        counter = counter + 1
        print(counter)
```

output:

```
3
1
1
1
Good Bye!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `from random import *` is BAD, and even more within a loop.